# Is there a way to change iPhone backup location?

Tags: iphone, backup

I don't have enough disk space on my PC to store whatever is backed up by iPhone. Is there a way to change location to where iPhone backs up the data? I want to back it up to my external hard drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [you can if using Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/180393/how-to-change-iphone-backup-location-on-windows).

Is OS X the backups seems to be stored in the following location ...

```
~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup
```

... but I don't think you can change that location.

Comment: But perhaps you can change it to be a symbolic link to a folder in an external drive.

Comment: @lhf yeah probably :)

Comment: Here's a page describing how to do it on a Mac: http://osxdaily.com/2011/03/05/how-to-move-the-iphoneipad-itunes-backup-folder-to-an-external-hard-drive/

Answer (score 0):

You can, however, drop a copy of that folder to your external drive - or include that folder in whatever backup/clone app you're using.